# Query a JSON list of dict

Tags: json

```
[{"time":136803,"price":"1.4545","amount":"0.0885","ID":"112969"},
 {"time":136804,"price":"2.5448","amount":"0.0568","ID":"5468489"},
 {"time":136805,"price":"1.8948","amount":"0.0478","ID":"898489"}]
```

I have a large JSON file like the one above.  It is a list of dictionaries.  I want to choose a time and find the value assoaciated with that time.  I will not know where in my list the time is located only the value for the time.  Is there a way I can say, for time 136804, make x = to price? Or should I loop through each value?  I also want to use this value (x) in a mathematical function.

My fist idea is to use brute force by going through each item and checking it for a matching time value in a loop.

Is this the best way?

Comment: As your data is array of objects, you should loop trough. But if you are able to change your data structure, use a map with 'time' beign key. Like {136803:{"time":136803,"price":"1.4545","amount":"0.0885","ID":"112969"}, ...}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SpahQL http://danski.github.io/spahql/ which we use to query JSON in order to select values and subsequently change them as required.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this recently. JSON file I had to query had around 6000 lines and around 500 JSON objects. My query function given below loops through the each object to select the matching objects, but it can fetch any result within few milliseconds.

```
var data = '[{"time":136803,"price":"1.4545","amount":"0.0885","ID":"112969"},'+                                       '{"time":136804,"price":"2.5448","amount":"0.0568","ID":"5468489"},'+                           '{"time":136805,"price":"1.8948","amount":"0.0478","ID":"898489"}]';

var data = JSON.parse(data);

var query = function(data, select, andwhere) {

        var return_array = [];

        $.each(data, function (i, obj) {

            var temp_obj = {};          

            var where = true;
            if (andwhere) {
                $.each(andwhere, function(j, wh) {
                    if (obj[wh.col] !== wh.val) {
                        where = false;
                    }
                });
            }
            if (where === false) {
                return;
            }

            $.each(obj, function (j, elem) {
                if (select.indexOf(j.trim())!==-1) {
                    temp_obj[j] = elem;
                }
            });

            return_array.push(temp_obj);
        });

        return return_array;
};
var result = query(data, ['price','amount'],[{"col":"time","val":136804}]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bejgy3sn/1/